# @NotNull validation on constructor arguments doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, notnull, javax

I have class with final fields. When I validate my fields on the constructor - there is a NullPointerException. I use javax.validation.constraints.NotNull. 
It is occurs only when I validate fields in the constructor. When I do it earlier - it`s work. Do you know why? 
//It is working good

```
public final class User { 

@NotNull private final String name; 
@NotNull private final List<Notes> notes; 

@JsonCreator public User(String name, List<Notes> notes){ 
this.name = name; 
this.notes = notes }



//It isn`t working, NPException 
public final class User { 

private final String name; 
private final List<Notes> notes; 

@JsonCreator 
public User(@NotNull String name, @NotNull List<Notes> notes){ 
this.name = name; 
this.notes = notes }
```

Comment: What do you think these annotations do - exactly I mean?

Comment: Check if field is null and then (if it is null) show nice validation error with messagge about null field. On https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation003.htm there are a samples with using it in the constructor

Comment: Are you running your application in an environment with a validator that actually checks those annotations? Otherwise, they're just text which does nothing except communicating intended use to programmers.

Comment: I just run it on spring boot app and it works only in first example (@NotNull before field declarations)

Comment: have you been able to get the second version to work?